# Import to Specific Excel Sheet from Access via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how to get data that I am importing into Excel from an Access table to import into a specific sheet (Either a sheet just called Sheet 2 or Access Data). I have the following code to get the data and to format it the way I want after import, but I can't get it to import into a specific sheet. Can I get assistance? Here's what I have:

Update to the code with resolution:

```
Sub getAccessData()

Dim DBFullName As String
Dim Connect As String, Source As String
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Col As Integer
Dim lngLastColumn As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim OXLSheet As Worksheet

Set OXLSheet = Worksheets("WorksheetName")

Worksheets("WorksheetName").Cells.Clear

'Datebase path info
DBFullName = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Database Backups\database.accdb"

'Open the connection for the database
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect


'Create RecordSet
Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
With Recordset

    'Data Filter
    Source = "SELECT * FROM tblRetirements WHERE [AllowEnteredInPayroll] Is Null AND ApplicationCancelled = 'No'"
    .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection


    'Write field Names
    For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("WorksheetName").Range("A5").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
    Next

    'Write Recordset
    Worksheets("WorksheetName").Range("A5").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
End With
ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
Set Recordset = Nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing



With OXLSheet
    lngLastColumn = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastColumn)), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, `SELECT*FROM`, should be `SELECT * FROM`.

If you want to import into a specific sheet, name `output`, please try replace:

1. `Range("A5").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name` with `Worksheets("output").Range("A5").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name`
2. `Range("A5").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset` with `Worksheets("output").Range("A5").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset`

Comment: Why? The import code that I have works as intended now. The issue that I have is that it wipes out everything on the current Active Sheet rather than on the sheet that I want to designate the data to go.

Comment: I removed the original SELECT criteria and replaced it with an "*" for simplicity and made a typo. However, the issue that i need assistance with is still outstanding. Can you help me with that?

Comment: There isn't an error with the code. What I need help with is how to specify the sheet that the data is imported into. Currently, the data imports into the current sheet, but I need to be able to trigger the code from a button that will reside on a sheet that is different than where I need the data to go.

Comment: I revised my answer.

Comment: I had to change a couple of other lines as well in order to make sure formatting on the active sheet didn't change, but this works great! Thank you! I really appreciate the helps. I changed the "Set OXLSheet = ActiveSheet" to "Set OXLSheet = Worksheets("Sheet6")" and "Cells.Clear" to "Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells.Clear". Everything works as intended now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy your data in a specific worksheet, for instance named `Sheet2`

```
' Declare a worksheet object
Dim objSheet As Worksheet

' initialize it
Set objSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Write field Names
For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
    objSheet.Range("A5").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
Next

'Write Recordset
objSheet.Range("A5").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic code to import the data from specific worksheets in all EXCEL files (worksheet names are the same in all files) that are located within a single folder. All of the EXCEL files' worksheets with the same worksheet names must have the data in the same layout and format.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim intWorksheets As Integer

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
Dim strWorksheets(1 To 3) As String

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file (this code assumes that each worksheet
' with the same name is being imported into a separate table
' for that specific worksheet name)
Dim strTables(1 To 3) As String

' Replace generic worksheet names with the real worksheet names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strWorksheets(1) = "GenericWorksheetName1"
strWorksheets(2) = "GenericWorksheetName2"
strWorksheets(3) = "GenericWorksheetName3"

' Replace generic table names with the real table names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strTables(1) = "GenericTableName1"
strTables(2) = "GenericTableName2"
strTables(3) = "GenericTableName3"

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
For intWorksheets = 1 To 3

      strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
      Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            strPathFile = strPath & strFile
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                  acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTables(intWorksheets), _
                  strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                  strWorksheets(intWorksheets) & "$"
            strFile = Dir()
      Loop

Next intWorksheets

End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for, but thank you for responding to my question.